# Using argument to access class

Tags: ruby, class, methods, arguments

I have two classes: one for creating songs and one for making a playlist, and the playlist takes songs.

```
class Song
  attr_accessor :title , :artist
  def initialize(title, artist)
    @title = title
    @artist = artist
  end
end

class Playlist
  def initialize(*songs)
    @playlist = []
    songs.each{|key|
      add(key)
    }
  end
  def add(*songs)
    songs.each {|key|
      @playlist << key
    }
  end 
end
```

I create songs:

```
anna_sun = Song.new("Anna Sun", "Walk The Moon")
girls = Song.new("Girls", "The 1975")
```

then add those songs to a new `Playlist`:

```
alternative = Playlist.new(anna_sun, girls)
```

I want to create a method inside of the `Playlist` class called `sort_by`. I want `sort_by` to take one argument that tells what to sort the playlist by. Here's what I came up with

```
class Playlist
  def sort_by(type)
    @playlist.sort_by! {|item|
      item.type
    }
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work for two reasons. One, when I try to call it

```
alternative.sort_by(artist)
```

it says that `artist` is not defined. And two, it says that `type` is an undefined method. I was wondering if there was a way to get the result that I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define

```
class Playlist
  def sort_by(type); @playlist.sort_by!(&type) end
end
```

and pass symbols

```
alternative.sort_by(:artist)
```

by the way, `Playlist` methods are very inefficient. They should be

```
class Playlist
  def initialize(*songs); @playlist = songs end
  def add(*songs); @playlist.concat(songs) end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
class Playlist

  def sort_by(type)
    @playlist.sort_by! {|item|
    item.public_send type
    }
  end

end
```

Instead of `item.public_send type` or `item.send type`, you could also use forms `eval` with all the evils they entail:

- `eval "item.#{type}"`
- `item.instance_eval type.to_s`

If I were you, I would simply delegate the call to `sort_by` on `Playlist` to `@playlist`, which would give me all the flexibility of the original `#sort_by` from the `Enumerable` mixin.

```
def sort_by!(*args,&blk)
    @playlist.sort_by! *args, &blk
 end
```

For delegating multiple methods, look into `forwardable` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html).